I am getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'installed' of undefined when I using localVue.use(Vuex); in my Jest test
I have test:
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import component from './component.vue';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);

jest.mock('infrastructure/store/global-instance', () => ({
    injectToReadonlyField: jest.fn()
}));

jest.mock('components/store/entity', () => ({
    ThemeClassName: jest.fn()
}));

describe('s-button', () => {
  let getters: any;
  let store: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    getters = {
      theme: () => 'material'
    };

    store = new Vuex.Store({
      modules: {
        style: {
          namespaced: true,
          getters
        }
      }
    });
  });

  it('Component does not empty and slot work fine', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(component, {
      store,
      localVue,
      slots: {
        default: 'Test button'
      }
    });
    expect(wrapper.html()).not.toEqual("");
    expect(wrapper.text()).not.toEqual("");
    expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('Test button');
  });

  it('Style classes work fine', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(component, { store, localVue });
    expect(wrapper.find('.s-button').exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(wrapper.find('.text').exists()).toBe(true);
  });

  it('When we click on button it generate event', () => {
    let wasGeneratedEvents = false;
    const wrapper = shallowMount(component, {
      store,
      localVue,
      listeners: {
        click: () => wasGeneratedEvents = true
      }
    });
    wrapper.find('.button').trigger('click');
    expect(wasGeneratedEvents).toBe(true);
  });
});

My .babelrc looks like this:
{
    "plugins": [ "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import" ],
    "presets": [
        "babel-preset-env"
    ]
}

jest.config.js:

const path = require('path');
const getPathAliases = require('./get-path-aliases');

const moduleNameMapper = {};
const pathAliases = getPathAliases();
for (const pathAliasName in pathAliases) {
    moduleNameMapper[`^${pathAliasName}/(.*)`] = `${path.resolve(__dirname, pathAliases[pathAliasName])}/$1`;
}

module.exports = {
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        "js",
        "jsx",
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "json",
        "vue"
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: moduleNameMapper,
    moduleDirectories: [
        "node_modules",
        "sources"
    ],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    testURL: "http://localhost/",
    testRegex: "\\.test\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
    testEnvironment: "node"
};

Here are the dependencies that I have in my testing package.json:
{
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "2.6.12",
        "vuex": "3.6.2"
    }

    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "14.0.0",
        "@vue/test-utils": "1.1.3",
        "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
        "ts-jest": "26.5.6"
    }
}

After running the test, I get the following error:
● Test suite failed to run
TypeError: Cannot read property 'installed' of undefined

  4 |
  5 | const localVue = createLocalVue();
> 6 | localVue.use(Vuex);
    |          ^
  7 |
  8 | jest.mock('infrastructure/store/global-instance', () => ({
  9 |     injectToReadonlyField: jest.fn()

Please tell me a solution or ideas to solve this problem
I tried changing dependency versions and rewriting the test, but it didn't help
